# My barplot with errorbars in ggplot2 is wrong

Tags: r, ggplot2

Minimal reproducible example is here:

```
library(ggplot2)

vals <- c(10, 12, 13, 20, 21, 28)
err <- c(0.85, 1.2, 0.9, 1.35, 2.2, 0.98)
cat <- c(rep("A",3),rep("B",3))

df <- data.frame(vals, err, cat)
df$cat<- as.factor(df$cat)

ggplot(df, aes(x=cat, y=vals, fill=vals)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity', position='dodge') +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=vals-err, ymax=vals+err), width=.1)
```

This code returns a plot like this:
[image: what is]

however I expected two columns next to each other per `cat`. Closer to this:

[image: should be]

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I believe the continuous fill is confusing `"dodge"`. One option is to switch to using `"dodge2"`. Alternatively add `group = factor(vals)` into your global `aes()` so dodge knows the categories to dodge on. I think the latter might be easiest if you are going to added the dodged bars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If each row is a separate observation, you need to make that explicit. Make an index variable, turn it into a factor, and put that on the x-axis.

If `obs` is repeated across categories (e.g. if both A and B have `obs` numbered 1, 2 and 3), then facet on `cat` with `facet_wrap(~ cat)`.

```r
vals <- c(10, 12, 13, 20, 21, 28)
err <- c(0.85, 1.2, 0.9, 1.35, 2.2, 0.98)
cat <- c(rep("A",3),rep("B",3))

df <- data.frame(vals, err, cat)
df$cat<- as.factor(df$cat)
df$obs <- factor(1:nrow(df))

ggplot(df, aes(x=obs, y=vals, fill=cat)) +
  geom_col(position='dodge') +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=vals-err, ymax=vals+err))
```

[image: enter result]